# Polymer in an apache based server

Tags: apache, polymer

I've tried to deploy the tutorial of Polymer in an Apache based server and I can't figure how to make it work. I've been looking for information about it but I can't find it, so I wonder... is it even possible to deploy it in Apache?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which one tutorial you try to deploy? It is packaged as `war`? See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html

Comment: This one: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/set-up and is not packaged, just uploaded the source code found in build/

Comment: In this tutorial supposed what you use `Polymer CLI` and start your website by  `polymer serve --open` command.

Comment: Yeah, that's for my local work, but when I want to deploy the final build in an apache server... I can't make it start properly

Comment: Apparently you should assemble your project so what your server can serve it

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late reply, but hopefully this'll help somebody else. I was able to deploy sample apps and custom apps to both Apache Web Server and Tomcat.

- Go to the root of your Polymer app
- polymer build
- cd build/unbundled
- Copy everything here to /var/www/html (Apache) or [TOMCAT_ROOT]/webapps/[YOUR_APP_FOLDER]